# I can't craft a Silver Watch? Terarria

Tags: terraria

I have all the materials needed for a Silver Watch. I have 9 chains and 22 Silver. (I know you need 10 silver and 1 chain) But I can't craft it? I try a Crafting Table, Furnace, Anvil, Advanced Crafting table. Why can't I craft it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crafting station for all watches is Table + Chair, such as the one you need to create a room, and not at any of the usual crafting stations like the ones you listed. Try crafting your watch there instead.

Comment: I assume the table and chair have to be kinda close to each toher, so you can "reach" both at the same time?

Comment: I usually have the chair right next to the table, I imagine the character is sitting in the chair and assembling the watch on the table.